# Makefile Runs Command Seemingly Randomly

Tags: makefile, x86, gnu-make

So, I have a project with GNU make. Sometimes, if I do a `make all`, it builds, but after that, builds the debug symbol file *again* and sometimes, it just works fine and reports `Nothing to be done for 'all'`.

Working as expected:

```
[cad@cordev kernel32]$ make clean
make -C boot clean
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/cad/Desktop/kernel/kernel32/boot'
rm -f main.o boot.o floppy_errs.o install_ints.o drivers/i8259A.o drivers/i8042o drivers/vga.o  *.ld.m4
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/cad/Desktop/kernel/kernel32/boot'
make -C kernel clean
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/cad/Desktop/kernel/kernel32/kernel'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'clean'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/cad/Desktop/kernel/kernel32/kernel'
rm -f *.out *.img *.sym

[cad@cordev kernel32]$ make all
make -C boot all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/cad/Desktop/kernel/kernel32/boot'
m4 ../m4/global.m4 m4/boot.m4 m4/asm.m4 ../m4/asm.m4 main.S  | \
as -o main.o --32 -g
m4 ../m4/global.m4 m4/boot.m4 m4/asm.m4 ../m4/asm.m4 boot.S  | \
as -o boot.o --32 -g
m4 ../m4/global.m4 m4/boot.m4 m4/asm.m4 ../m4/asm.m4 floppy_errs.S  | \
as -o floppy_errs.o --32 -g
m4 ../m4/global.m4 m4/boot.m4 m4/asm.m4 ../m4/asm.m4 install_ints.S  | \
as -o install_ints.o --32 -g
m4 ../m4/global.m4 m4/boot.m4 m4/asm.m4 ../m4/asm.m4 drivers/i8259A.S  | \
as -o drivers/i8259A.o --32 -g
m4 ../m4/global.m4 m4/boot.m4 m4/asm.m4 ../m4/asm.m4 drivers/i8042.S  | \
as -o drivers/i8042.o --32 -g
m4 ../m4/global.m4 m4/boot.m4 m4/asm.m4 ../m4/asm.m4 drivers/vga.S  | \
as -o drivers/vga.o --32 -g
m4 ../m4/global.m4 m4/boot.m4 boot.ld  > boot.ld.m4
ld -T boot.ld.m4 main.o boot.o floppy_errs.o install_ints.o drivers/i8259A.o drvers/i8042.o drivers/vga.o  -melf_i386
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/cad/Desktop/kernel/kernel32/boot'
objcopy --only-keep-debug boot.out boot.sym
objcopy --strip-debug --strip-unneeded boot.out
objcopy -O binary boot.out boot.img

[cad@cordev kernel32]$ make all
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

Working oddly:

```
[cad@cordev kernel32]$ make clean
make -C boot clean
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/cad/Desktop/kernel/kernel32/boot'
rm -f main.o boot.o floppy_errs.o install_ints.o drivers/i8259A.o drivers/i8042o drivers/vga.o  *.ld.m4
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/cad/Desktop/kernel/kernel32/boot'
make -C kernel clean
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/cad/Desktop/kernel/kernel32/kernel'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'clean'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/cad/Desktop/kernel/kernel32/kernel'
rm -f *.out *.img *.sym

[cad@cordev kernel32]$ make all
make -C boot all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/cad/Desktop/kernel/kernel32/boot'
m4 ../m4/global.m4 m4/boot.m4 m4/asm.m4 ../m4/asm.m4 main.S  | \
as -o main.o --32 -g
m4 ../m4/global.m4 m4/boot.m4 m4/asm.m4 ../m4/asm.m4 boot.S  | \
as -o boot.o --32 -g
m4 ../m4/global.m4 m4/boot.m4 m4/asm.m4 ../m4/asm.m4 floppy_errs.S  | \
as -o floppy_errs.o --32 -g
m4 ../m4/global.m4 m4/boot.m4 m4/asm.m4 ../m4/asm.m4 install_ints.S  | \
as -o install_ints.o --32 -g
m4 ../m4/global.m4 m4/boot.m4 m4/asm.m4 ../m4/asm.m4 drivers/i8259A.S  | \
as -o drivers/i8259A.o --32 -g
m4 ../m4/global.m4 m4/boot.m4 m4/asm.m4 ../m4/asm.m4 drivers/i8042.S  | \
as -o drivers/i8042.o --32 -g
m4 ../m4/global.m4 m4/boot.m4 m4/asm.m4 ../m4/asm.m4 drivers/vga.S  | \
as -o drivers/vga.o --32 -g
m4 ../m4/global.m4 m4/boot.m4 boot.ld  > boot.ld.m4
ld -T boot.ld.m4 main.o boot.o floppy_errs.o install_ints.o drivers/i8259A.o drvers/i8042.o drivers/vga.o  -melf_i386
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/cad/Desktop/kernel/kernel32/boot'
objcopy --only-keep-debug boot.out boot.sym
objcopy --strip-debug --strip-unneeded boot.out
objcopy -O binary boot.out boot.img

[cad@cordev kernel32]$ make all
objcopy --only-keep-debug boot.out boot.sym # HERE

[cad@cordev kernel32]$ make all
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

(I marked the relevant line with `# HERE`. I also inserted blank lines to improve readability.)

The thing here is that this happens seemingly randomly. In fact, those two examples I gave happened successively.
I noticed that a longer time between `make clean`, `make all`, and `make all` *sometimes* caused the redundant build step, whereas executing the commands tightly together *never* caused that. I just tried like 10x, though.

The makefile is as follows:

```
# Parameters passed to GNU make.
# `dbg=y|n': decides whether debugging mode is on or not.
# `sep_boot=y|n': decides whether bootloader and kernel should be seperate
# images or not.
# TODO: add functionality for these parameters

SHELL = /bin/bash

%.sym: %.out
        objcopy --only-keep-debug $< $@

%.img: %.out
        objcopy --strip-debug --strip-unneeded $<
        objcopy -O binary $< $@

%.out:
        make -C $* all

# TODO: merge run and debug targets and decide to debug or not using the dbg
# parameter.

boot_debug: boot.sym boot.img
        qemu-system-i386 -fda boot.img -s -S &
        gdb -x dbg.gdb

all: boot.sym boot.img #kernel.img kernel.sym

boot.sym boot.img: boot.out

kernel.sym kernel.img: kernel.out


clean:
        make -C boot clean
        make -C kernel clean
        rm -f *.out *.img *.sym


.PHONY: boot_debug all clean
```

If you want to reproduce on your own, a git clone can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/qrzbl/kernel32/archive/e108d76090ba05bc4767dda08001a4594946590f.zip).

So, what's the problem here? And where is the correlation between the additional build step and the time passed between the commands (or is it just a misobservation)? GNU make relies on timestamps to determine the newest version of a file... maybe that's somehow related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first line of the recipe of this rule:

```
%.img: %.out
        objcopy --strip-debug --strip-unneeded $<
        objcopy -O binary $< $@
```

is modifying its prerequisite (`boot.out`), which updates its timestamp.  Depending on exactly when that happens, what kind of filesystem you have (whether it supports sub-second timestamps for example), etc., it may be that after this rule is complete the timestamp for `boot.out` now has a newer timestamp than the previously created `boot.sym`, and so when you re-run make it will decide to rebuild `boot.sym`.

You need to rewrite this rule in such a way that it doesn't modify the prerequisite; maybe:

```
%.img: %.out
        objcopy --strip-debug --strip-unneeded $< $<.tmp
        objcopy -O binary $<.tmp $@
        rm -f $<.tmp
```

I'm not sure if objcopy will write to stdout/read from stdin, but if so you can use a pipeline instead.